# jquery dialog title and close bar remove

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, ember.js, dialog

I have a jquery dialog with title and close bar. After that I am loading an another dialog called for confirmation. In my confirmation dialog UI I don't want the 'title' and 'close' button. If I remove title and close button using dialog 'open' method, in my confirmation dialog it's working fine with the title remove changes. But my backend dialog also getting removed with the title and close button. I only need that for the current dialog not for the parent one.

I am here attaching the UI for your reference.

[image: First dialog with the title and close]

[image: another popup without close and title]

In the first image, I am initializing with the jquery dialog with the title and close button.

In the second one, I am removing title and close with open function while init the dialog.

In my second dialog init,

```
open: function (event, ui) {
        $(".ui-dialog-titlebar-close", ui.dialog | ui).remove(); 
        $(".ui-dialog-titlebar", ui.dialog | ui).remove();
},
```

If, I do remove like this, I am getting removed title all the dialog. I need to remove title for the specific dialog.Kindly help me out of this.

Comment: Can you please provide a working fiddle, so that we don't need to create another full fledged script.

Comment: What do you think this `ui.dialog | ui` does?

Comment: You should use a selector that includes the id of the specific dialog from which you want to remove these elements.  Like `$("#my-dialog .ui-dialog-titlebar-close").remove();`.

Comment: @PraveenKumar here is the working fiddle [link] (http://jsfiddle.net/PTXZV/64/)

Comment: @raduation I did the one using selector event it applies the same. :-(

Comment: @PriyangaV Got the issue. You have to specify the title ID.

Comment: @PriyangaV Eager to know if my fiddle works!

Comment: @PraveenKumar where is your working fiddle?

Comment: @PriyangaV Check out my answer please. The link to the fiddle is there.

Comment: @PriyangaV http://imgur.com/a/xinCe#0 - Is this the expected output?

Comment: @PraveenKumar yes. This is was I expected exactly. And one more thing, I use three set of buttons for the first dialog. Those button colors are same. In my second dialog I need to give some color, if I do apply it applies to the backend button too. :-( 


I do used to apply button color using like this,  "$('.ui-dialog-buttonpane button:eq(0)'), $('.ui-dialog-buttonpane button:eq(1)')"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/87756/discussion-between-praveen-kumar-and-priyanga-v).

Comment: @PriyangaV Can you come to the chat?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I found your issue. You were generalizing the title. You need to specifically do it. Try this:

```
$(function () {
    $( "#dialog1" ).dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        height:'300', // No I18N
        width: '300', // No I18N
        resize: false,
    });

    $("#opener").click(function() {
        $("#dialog1").dialog('open');
    });

    $( "#dialog2" ).dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        height:'100', // No I18N
        width: '100', // No I18N
        resize: false,
        open: function (event, ui) {
            // Do not generalize here!
            $("#ui-id-2").closest(".ui-dialog-titlebar").remove();
        },
    });

    $("#opener1").click(function() {
        $("#dialog2").dialog('open');
    });

});
```

**Preview**

[image]

[image]

[image]

Album: https://i.stack.imgur.com/hadAJ.jpg

**Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/PTXZV/65/**

Comment: Hi Praveen, Couldn't connect you with chat. so here is the fiddle,  http://jsfiddle.net/PTXZV/66/

Comment: @PriyangaV So what's happening now?

Comment: here, button color doesn't change. but in my case it happens. those green buttons gets grey when I open the second dialog.

Comment: Couldn't give the full code. Is there any way to identify the first dialog button pane like "title" as '$("#ui-id-2")' ?

Comment: Yes, you can get the ID using `this.id` and compare it.

Comment: Okay, I will do and come back, if I face any issues.